# Authorization header not sent using AFNetworking

Tags: heroku, authorization, afnetworking

I'm developing an iOS app that makes frequent requests to a web server, and I'm using AFNetworking (which I very much like). However, I'm running into a problem with authorization that I just can't solve.

The server requires me to provide an authorization header in order to get the response that I want. Specifically, the authorization headers should be like so:

```
Authorization = "ApiKey some-user-name:someNumericalApiKey"
```

I'm using AFNetworking throughout the project, and everything works fine, except for this authorization issue. I'm using the following code:

```
[myClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:@"ApiKey some-user-name:someNumericalApiKey"];
```

where `myClient` points to an AFHTTPClient object. Strange enough, when I log the request in XCode using `AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger`, the logger claims that I have the correct headers set. However, the authorization header does not seem to reach the server - I can't see it in the server log.

To isolate the problem, I've tried to make the exact same request using good old `NSURLRequest`, as well as `curl`, and the `requests` library in Python - all of these work fine, i.e. the authorization header is sent & received (i.e. I can see it in the server log), and the server response is what it should be.

If anyone has run into the same problem (and has found a solution) I would very much appreciate to hear from you.

Thanks.

Comment: The service being hit is a Django application on Heroku.

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. Very weird.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes (especially with Django) this is caused by redirection stripping of header parameters.  For instance, /Object redirects to /Object/ in the background and removes the necessary auth parameter during the switch.

If you're using [AFNetworkActivityLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger) with level `AFLoggerLevelDebug` then you should be able to check this out in the console.  If you see a POST request with /Object and the response with /Object/ then this might indicate redirection stripping is taking place.

Comment: This answer is the correct answer. Reference : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2116

Answer (score 0):

If you construct your operation manually then the defaultHeaders are not applied, that might be the cause of your problem.